# How i can realize multiple pagination(drf)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination, postman

If I'll send get request like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRTVr.png), i need to have multiple pagination (LimitOffset and PageNumber).

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", null=True)
    hashtag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_hit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

from .models import *
from .serializers import ProductsSerializer


class PaginationProducts(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 2
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 2


class ProductsAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    pagination_class = PaginationProducts
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import *


class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_photo_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        photo_url = obj.fingerprint.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(photo_url)
```

I need something that can help API client choose number of page and quantity of posts on that page. Think that in this case i need NumberPagePagination and LimitOffsetPagination.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `products` of the `views.py`, `serializers.py`, and the `models.py` files here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to create the custom pagination class.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination

class ProductsAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

The `offset` value corresponds to the `page * size` in the original pagination and the `limit` value corresponds to the `size`.